# Very tiny emulator window launched from the iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

After a few weeks of normal iPhone SE simulator window size all of a sudden it is quite tiny: `75x147`

[image]

I did stop/restart the simulator and that had no effect.  I then *restarted xcode* but the tiny emulator persists.   What can be done to recover the normal emulator dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a setting available on the `menu`: hitting `CMD-1` or `CMD-2` resets this to normal:

[image]

It is not clear what caused this situation in the first place though likely I inadvertently hit some "magic" key combination.